# Dropdown CSS with local storage

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, local-storage

A user can pick a theme from the dropdown and selected theme would be stored in local storage. While it can save the dropdown value in localstorage, it's not calling the stylesheet. Please help, thanks!

Pardon the Frankenstein type of code. JS's foreign to me, I'm a designer by trade.

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="style1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="s1" id="s1"/>
</head>
<body>

<select id="mySelect" class="test">
    <option value="style1.css">Option A</option>
    <option value="style2.css">Option B</option>
    <option value="style3.css">Option C</option>
</select>


<!--local storage-->
<script>
 $('.test').change(function() {
    localStorage.setItem(this.id, this.value);
}).val(function() {
    return localStorage.getItem(this.id)
});
</script>
<!--dropdown css-->

 <script>
        function setStyleSource (linkID, sourceLoc) {
      var theLink = document.getElementById(linkID);
      theLink.href = sourceLoc;
      console.log(theLink.href);
    }

    document.getElementById("mySelect").addEventListener("change", function(){
        var selected = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
        setStyleSource ("s1", selected)
    });
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

1.the dropdown to change css works.
2.localstorage for selected option works.
**But** the stored selected option doesn't actually show its own css sheet (it's displaying the default css instead).

Comment: What does your console.log show?

Comment: I think the only thing that's changing the stylesheet is a selection from the dropdown, which changes the link (you might need to refresh the page?) I could be wrong but it doesn't look like calling storage is doing anything.

Comment: @dgrogan it's showing blank

Comment: @wazz so far by changing the dropdown, it replaces the stylesheet without needing to refresh. localstorage stores the dropdown option so the option stays the same after refresh. But the option doesn't trigger the change in stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Changing dropdownvalue with `val()` doesnt trigger `change` event, you will have to trigger it manually after setting the value by doing:

```
$('.test').val(localStorage.getItem(this.id)).trigger('change'); // OR .change()
```

Also add event listener for `change` **before** triggering the same:

```
function setStyleSource(linkID, sourceLoc) {
  var theLink = document.getElementById(linkID);
  theLink.href = sourceLoc;
  console.log(theLink.href);
}

document.getElementById("mySelect").addEventListener("change", function() {
  var selected = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
  setStyleSource("s1", selected)
});

$('.test').change(function() {
  localStorage.setItem(this.id, this.value);
}).val(function() {
  return localStorage.getItem(this.id)
}).trigger('change');
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've added your input, but doesn't seem to work. But I'm not sure if I've added it correctly [link] (http://imaginaryzebra.com/feature%20test/css_dropdown%2Blocalstorage.html) 

Ultimately, i'd like the page to display the respective css after refreshing the page. it currently shows the selected dropdown option after refreshing the page, but it's not using the respective css